# Preg_match doesn't match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a Spanish phone number. I have a regular expression declared:

```
$telefono_regex = '/^(6|7|8|9)[0-9]{8}$/';
```

And I check the number:

```
if (!preg_match($telefono_regex, $telefono)){
     array_push($errores, 'telefono');
}
```

Why does this always return false? I have checked in https://regex101.com/ and found match with the same numbers.

Comment: if it really returns false and not 1 or 0 then an error has occured, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: What is the number format you are trying to match?

Comment: Give us your regex101.com concrete examples where you say match is performed

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your question and in your first try on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/79l62I/1/) were different.

Assuming you want to check numbers with optional dash or space every three digits(as in your first try on regex101.com), you can try this:

```
$telefono_regex = '/^[6-9]{3}(?:[ -]?[0-9]{3}){2}$/';
```

- `^[6-9]{3}`: three digits from 6 to 9
- `(?:[ -]?[0-9]{3})`: non-capturing group to match zero or one space or dash (`[ -]?`) followed by three numbers (`[0-9]{3}`)
- `{2}`: to match 2 occurrences of the non-capturing group

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/f55KQ1/2).

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little more why the OP's one *doesn't* work while this one *does* in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

Comment: @ChristianRau You're right. I added some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working PHP-fiddle

http://rextester.com/ESYBOO56762

```
$telefono_regex = '/^[6-9][0-9]{8}$/';

$num='678912345';
echo preg_match($telefono_regex,$num);
```

answer is `1`. I replaced your first `(6|7|8|9)`-group by a shorter `[6-9]`, but both should work in the same way.